# JPA - ManyToOne - JoinTable - cannot update a field

Tags: java, jpa, join

I have the following situation:

AnagraficaIscritti.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ANAGRAFICA_ISCRITTI")
public class AnagraficaIscritti implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID_EMAIL",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private long idEmail;

    private String email;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Newsletter 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="anagraficaIscrittis")
    private List<Newsletter> newsletters;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to IscrizioniEmail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="anagraficaIscritti")
    private List<IscrizioniEmail> iscrizioniEmails;
```

Newsletter.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="NEWSLETTER")
public class Newsletter implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="ID_NEWSLETTER")
        private long idNewsletter;

        //bi-directional many-to-many association to AnagraficaIscritti
        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(
            name="ISCRIZIONI_EMAIL"
            , joinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="ID_NEWSLETTER")
                }
            , inverseJoinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="ID_EMAIL")
                }
            )
        private List<AnagraficaIscritti> anagraficaIscrittis;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to IscrizioniEmail
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="newsletter")
        private List<IscrizioniEmail> iscrizioniEmails;
```

IscrizioniEmail.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="iscrizioni_email")
public class IscrizioniEmail implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        @EmbeddedId
        private IscrizioniEmailPK id;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name="SUBSCRIPTION_DATE")
        private Date subscriptionDate;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to AnagraficaIscritti
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_EMAIL",insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private AnagraficaIscritti anagraficaIscritti;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to Newsletter
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_NEWSLETTER", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Newsletter newsletter;
```

IscrizioniEmailPK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class IscrizioniEmailPK implements Serializable {
        //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Column(name="ID_EMAIL", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private long idEmail;

        @Column(name="ID_NEWSLETTER", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private long idNewsletter;
```

When I tried to create an Object AnagraficaIscritti and an Object Newsletter, a record is automatically inserted also in IscrizioniEmail. For example I create:

```
 ANAGRAFICA_ISCRITTI
 ID_EMAIL           EMAIL
  1           john.doe@gmail.com

 NEWSLETTER
 ID_NEWSLETTER      NEWSLETTER
      1               sport

 ISCRIZIONI_EMAIL
  ID_EMAIL   ID_NEWSLETTER   SUBSCRIPTION_DATE
     1             1               NULL
```

But what's the correct way to update SUBSCRIPTION_DATE (with the current timestamp), which is null? If I try to create an Object IscrizioniEmail i got duplicate key errors and so on.

Comment: Have you tried creating an `@Entity` class `IscrizioniEmail`?

Comment: I don't understand. The entity class IscrizioniEmail exists.

Comment: Thanks, defining a default value works:
`SUBSCRIPTION_DATE` DATETIME DEFAULT NOW()
I think JPA is sometimes very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a default value for `SUBSCRIPTION_DATE` in your `ISCRIZIONI_EMAIL` table which value would be the current date. So that you don't need to send it from Java.

If you need to send that value from Java, then you could execute an update query using `IscrizioniEmail` entity class just after inserting in `Newsletter` and `AnagraficaIscritti` tables.